# Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed? python 3.7.0 issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, windows-10, lxml

As the title states i'm having an issue trying to install lxml.

I've updated python to 3.7.0, my pip is at v18.0 and i've visited https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#libxml-python to get the file lxml‑4.2.5‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl and try to install it via pip.

My first issue is that the whl file is rejected and I get the output 'is not a supported wheel on this platform' and then secondly if I just try and install lxml via pip then it doesn't seem to fix the issue that it could not find function xmlCheckVersion.

Any help would be appreciated, this is being done on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Please, be sure you have Windows 64-bit and python 64-bit installed.

Comment: So `pip install lxml` succeded without error?

Comment: pip install lxml works fine but I still get the error that it could not find function

Comment: could you add the code snippet you are trying to run and the full traceback? Also add if you have multiple python versions installed on your system pls